ASP.Net Core 8 / Angular 17 and Authentication with OAuth
In 'legacy' ASP.Net Core/Angular applications we have been using OAuth Authentication in our applications, but it appears to no longer work with the newer angular proxy code.
In Startup's ConfigureServices / Configure we do:
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
 {
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
 .AddCookie(options =>
 {
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10); //default is 14days
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/UserAccessDenied";
 })
 .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
 {
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Auth:Authority"];
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Auth:ClientId"];
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier };

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
      OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
      {
      return Task.CompletedTask;
      },
      OnRemoteFailure = context =>
      {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/401");
        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
    };
  });

and:
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();
      app.Use(async (context, next) =>
      {
        if (!context.User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated) {
          await context.ChallengeAsync(); 
        }
        else { 
          await next(); 
        }
      });

What would happen previously is:

Angular would make a REST API call
The backend would detect the user is unauthorized and redirect to OAuth server
OAuth would return to the backend /signin-oidc
An authentication ping would occur
Then the backend would continue with responding with the REST request (assuming user was authenticated)

With the new Angular proxy configuration:

Angular makes the rest call, which becomes a 302 xhr / Redirect
The authorization return with a 302 Found but the browser gives an error related to No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header being present:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://authuat.XXXX.com/as/authorization.oauth2?
client_id=rms-it-generic&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44300%2Fsignin-oidc&
response_type=code&
scope=openid%20profile%20email%20employee_id&
code_challenge=WX-AJ7CmsRMr0Re3V5i18k0u9xjB7eHnK8L1bADcJrY&
code_challenge_method=S256&
response_mode=form_post<snip>&
x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0
&x-client-ver=7.1.2.0'
(redirected from 'https://localhost:4200/weatherforecast') 
from origin 'https://localhost:4200' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am not sure how I can get the proxy configuration working properly.
I figure I may be missing something simple, but pretty stuck after about 8 hours of going in circles.
I used the default ASP.Net Core/Angular app from the template with the WeatherForecast example.
Just changed the port of my backend to match one of our apps (https://localhost:44300) and
then added the authentication logic.
proxy.conf.js file is:
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'https://localhost:44300';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
    ],
    target,
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;

If anyone has suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

I think the main issue with the proxy being implemented on the SPA side, rather than the legacy SpaProxy on the ASP.Net Core side, is that there does not appear to be a way to configure CORS with the PROXY_CONFIG configuration... At least that I have been able to find so far...

You can try to configure the relevant CORS policy in the program.cs file. Refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I do have the CORS configured on the backend - but with the issue is on the front-end.
The angular  proxy doesnt' seem to support cors configuration, or I'm just missing something blatantly obvious
